# JSON with Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I would like to parse a varialbe name into a JSON string:

JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "2000",
            "buttons": [{
                "text": systemvar.continue,
            }]
        }
}
```

systemvar.continue is defined in Javascript.

How do I write the JSON code to use the Javascript variable?

Any ideas?

Best Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a safe, restricted subset of JavaScript's syntax. If you want to allow *any* JavaScript syntax, including that which is potentially unsafe, use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) instead of `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 3):

If `systemvar.continue` is defined in JavaScript, then make your JSON valid like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "2000",
            "buttons": [{
                "text": "continue", // <-- only pass the property name
            }]
        }
}
```

And then access the `"continue"` property of `systemvar` using square bracket notation.

```
var result = systemvar[ json.items[0].buttons[0].text ];
```

Of course this is hardcoded and assumes your parsed JSON is referenced in a variable called `json`. I assume you're traversing the structure, and will come across `text:"continue"` at some point. When you get there, plug it in as the property name.

```
// in traversal
systemvar[ val.text ];
```

---

I'd also suggest that you avoid the word `continue` since it's a reserved word, though it will work with a string in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can use is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

The client-side would have this html code:

```
<script>
function readData(json_arr) {
    //`json_arr` will be the javascript array.
    //do whatever you want to do with the array here.
}
</script>
<script src="your_server.example.com/getData?jsonp=readData"></script>
```

And the server would return:

```
readData(
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "2000",
            "buttons": [{
                "text": systemvar.continue,
            }]
        }
    }
)
```

Note that this means that your returned "JSON array" is automatically executed by the browser's javascript engine.